# cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object, trying to plot a bar graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm working on this lab for a class and I keep getting the error from the title. What we're supposed to be doing is making a bar graph from a csv file, and I don't really know why I'm getting these errors but it looks like its due to the line

```
college_names, college_enrollments = read_file(file_name)
```

which I am not supposed to change.
Here is the whole code (I also added in the plt.whatever lines):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def read_file(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    dlist = []
    a = []
    b = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            x = line.split(",")            
            a.append(x[0])
            b.append(x[1])
            f.close

    college_names = np.array(a)
    college_enrollments = np.array(b)

# -------------------------------------------------

def main(file_name):
    college_names, college_enrollments = read_file(file_name)


    plt.bar(college_names, college_enrollments)
    plt.xlabel('Department')
    plt.ylabel('# of students')
    plt.title('amount of students by department')

    plt.show()
# -------------------------------------------------

main("fall-2019.csv")
```

Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\letho\OneDrive\Desktop\csci\hunchback2.py", line 53, in 
    main("fall-2019.csv")
  File "C:\Users\letho\OneDrive\Desktop\csci\hunchback2.py", line 38, in main
    college_names, college_enrollments = read_file(file_name)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace?

Comment: @DarrenChristopher  I added what I think you were asking for

Comment: You forgot to return the arrays from your function.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You are totally right I can't believe I was racking my brain over something that simple, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add   `return (college_names, college_enrollments)` in the end of your `read_file` function. Your current function doesn’t have any return so python couldn’t unpack it as it expects a collection.